# How to iterate over Set and add elements to it in java?

Tags: java, iterator, set

I want to iterate over a Set and if some condition meet I want to add elements to it. 
While I am doing this, I am getting "ConcurrentModificationException". 
When I looked for the answer, I found that in case of listIterator we have add() and remove() method but I can't use list as I also have to take care of duplicates.

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Edit:

```
int[] A = {1,2,3,4,5,10,6,7,9};
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
s.add(1);
Iterator i = s.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
      int temp = i.next();
      int x = next element of array A;
      if(x%2==0){
          s.add(temp*x);
          }
       }
```

But it is throwing ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Help us help you - please share a sample set, and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: Add the created objects to another collection, and when the loop is done, add all the elements of the new collection to the set?

Comment: I am adding elements multiple times, so can't create new object every time.

Comment: A HashSet has no ordering. So even if this was allowed, you couldn't be sure it the iterator would return the element you just added or not. Use a List, and before adding a new element to the list, check if it is already present in a set. If not, add the element to the list and to the set. Unless of course the array is so short anyway that using a set is overkill, and that you can check if the list already contains the element.

Comment: But checking every time whether the element is already present or not in the list will take extra time.

Comment: Which is why my first suggestion is to use a parallel set. Please read my comment carefully.

Comment: But memory usage will go up by a significant amount.

Comment: @KaranKanwal - you can’t change the set while iterating. It will always give you concurrent modification exception if you do that. JB Nizet is right. You should follow that solution. Is there a reason you are using a Set and iterating over it and trying to change the elements at the same time?

Comment: @KaranKanwal it is hard to understand what your goal is. In the example code you iterate over the set and the array at the same time. Could you please provide an example which is closer to your actual use case or describe the goal you want to achive in more detail?

Comment: I doubt that this code will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`, as it doesn’t even compile. “`next element of array A`” lacks an actual operation. Even if we ignore that, the loop will simply terminate after the first iteration, as the condition is not fulfilled for `1 * 1` and then, there is no next element in the `Set`. Generally, iterating over two differently sized things in one loop doesn’t make much sense. Fixing this fundamental logic error likely brings you to a solution that doesn’t need to modify the set you’re iterating…

Answer (score 0):

> How to iterate over Set and add elements to it in java?

It cannot be done.  Certainly, not with a `HashSet` or `TreeSet`.  You will probably need to find an alternative way of coding your algorithm that doesn't rely on doing that.

The normal solution is to create a temporary list, add elements to that list, then when you have finished iterating use `addAll` to add the list elements to the set.  But that won't work here because you appear to want your iterator to see the new elements that you have added.

A second approach would be use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and `Collections::newSetFromMap` instead of a `HashSet`.  Iterating a concurrent collection won't give a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  However, the flipside is that there are no guarantees that the iterator will see all of the elements that were added during the iteration.  So this probably wouldn't work (reliably) for your example.